# Swift - Value of Type ViewController has no member *functionName*

Tags: ios, swift, function

In my app i have several scenarios, each showing a different `UIAlertController`, so i created a function to show this alert, but i can't seem to call self.Function inside the "okAction" . I'm getting this error :

> Value of type `'ViewController'` has no member `'doAction'`

Here's the code :

```
func showAlertController( titleOfAlert: String, messageOfAlert : String, doAction : () )
{
    let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: titleOfAlert, message: messageOfAlert, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in

        self.doAction()
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
    }

    refreshAlert.addAction(okAction)
    refreshAlert.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here's one of the functions that i'm calling :

```
func changeLabel1()
{
    label.text = "FOR BUTTON 1"
}
```

How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. remove the `self` in front of `doAction()` since you do not call the action on the object self.
2. If you do that the compiler will tell you
   `Invalid use of '()' to call  a value  of non-function type '()'`. That is the case because `doAction` is no function but an empty tuple. A function has input parameters and a return type. Therefore the type of `doAction` should be `() -> Void` - it takes no input and returns `Void`, i.e. does not return anything.

The code should be like this:

```
func showAlertController( titleOfAlert: String, messageOfAlert : String, doAction : () -> Void ) {
    ...
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { action in
        doAction()
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to pass the `action` to the `doAction` method you would have to change the type to `(UIAlertAction) -> Void` and call it via `doAction(action)`.

Comment: Thank you! I picked your answer because it explains more

Answer (score 1):

From your code *doAction* is the third parameter of function
*showAlertController*.

so 
First: change **doAction : ()** to **doAction: ()->()**
It means that doAction is a [Closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) without parameters and empty return.

Second: the call shouldn't be **self.doAction()** but just **doAction()**
Because its a parameter and not an instance variable

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to specify a closure is like this:

```
func showAlertController( titleOfAlert: String, messageOfAlert : String, doAction : (() -> Void) ){

   // and then call it like that
   doAction()

}
```

The key thing here is that you cannot call `this.doAction()` because the parameter you pass into the function is not a property on your controller, right ?

Comment: Edit: Still giving me the same error. Thanks for the fast reply (i replied before the Edit appear, i'll check it

Comment: It worked. I picked luk2302's answer because it explained what was wrong. Thanks though!

Comment: @user3902533 No worries, key thing is that you solved your problem. I wanted to expand on my answer, but I saw that you already found what you were looking for...